# Is there a standalone i18n library in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, localization, internationalization, locale, i18n-gem

In Ruby I can't find any localization modules. Are there any or should I use some external library? I have found I18n gem but I don't know if I can use it in standalone application (without Rails). Moreover I need some methods to localize floats and I can't see it in I18n gem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried r18n?

https://github.com/ai/r18n

It also localizes floats:

https://github.com/ai/r18n/blob/master/r18n-core/spec/locale_spec.rb

Answer (score 2):

There is no localization module in the Ruby stdlib. You can use the `i18n` gem outside Rails, which is probably most downloaded and popular internationalization plugin for Ruby.

If you're looking for a more lightweight version, I recently released [MiniI18n](https://github.com/markets/mini_i18n): a simple, flexible and fast Ruby internationalization and localization library. It also supports dates and numbers localization, interpolations, pluralization, fallbacks, nested keys and more. Its API is quite similar to `i18n` library. See  [benchmark here](https://gist.github.com/markets/eab1d4a82d22146b577a085d00f1185d).

Translations examples:

```
>> MiniI18n.t(:hello)
=> "Hello"
>> MiniI18n.t(:hello_with_name, name: 'John Doe')
=> "Hello John Doe"
>> MiniI18n.t('notifications.unread', count: 0)
=> "no unread notifications"
>> MiniI18n.t([:hello, :bye])
=> ["Hello", "Bye"]
```

Number localization examples:

```
>> MiniI18n.l(1000.5)
=> "1,000.5"
>> MiniI18n.l(1000.5, as: :currency)
=> "1,000.5 $"
```

Date localization examples:

```
>> MiniI18n.l(Date.new(2018, 8, 15))
=> "Wednesday 15, August, 2018"
>> MiniI18n.l(Date.new(2018, 8, 15), format: :short)
=> "15 Aug 18"
```